# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I am still learning jQuery.  I am trying to write a script that finds any element with rel="toggleSelect".  It should add an onclick attribute with my function that enables or disables all checkboxes in the provided group("actions" array).  I am getting an error that says "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token }".  I cannot figure out why.  I think it has something to do with the selector for the groupId perm input.  TYIA!!!

```
$(function(){
        $('input[rel="toggleSelect"]').on("click", function(){
                var groupId = $(this).attr("id");
                var actions = new Array("read", "create", "reply", "moderate");
                for(var i=0;i<=actions.length;i++){
                    checkboxName = $('input[name="perms[" + groupId + "][" + actions[i] + "]"');
                    if(checkboxName.is(":enabled")){
                        checkboxName.prop("disabled", true);
                    } else {
                        checkboxName.prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                }
        }
    });
```

An example of the input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="perms[1][read]" value="1" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix the missing parenthesis when binding your click event handler, there's a problem with this line:

```
checkboxName = $('input[name="perms[" + groupId + "][" + actions[i] + "]"');
```

That looks as though you're attempting to dynamically build the string by concatenating the values of some variables with string literals, but you're using the wrong type of quotes to end the string before concatenating. The use of double quotes, when you actually need single, results in a completely invalid jQuery selector.

Change it to the following:

```
checkboxName = $('input[name="perms[' + groupId + '][' + actions[i] + ']"');
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just realized I'm using the wrong prop as well!  Just enables/disables, not check/uncheck lol.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `)`. Also, you need to instantiate your `checkboxName` by var keyword as well as concatenating your selectors other way, final code should look like:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[rel="toggleSelect"]').on("click", function () {
        var groupId = $(this).attr("id");
        var actions = new Array("read", "create", "reply", "moderate");
        for (var i = 0; i <= actions.length; i++) {
            var checkboxName = $('input[name="perms[' + groupId + '][' + actions[i] + ']"');
            if (checkboxName.is(":enabled")) {
                checkboxName.prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                checkboxName.prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    }); // <-- here
});
```

Comment: ideally want a `;` there too :)

Comment: Ok, so that got rid of the token error, now when I click on the checkbox, it gives me Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name="perms[" + groupId + "][" + actions[i] + "]"

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 You need to instantiate your `checkboxName` by `var` keyword as well as concatenating your selectors other way, try my updated code

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 I addressed that in my answer; you're creating the selector string incorrectly. You're not actually ending the string literal before trying to concatenate the variable values.

Comment: @Felix Your updated code is incorrect - you shouldn't have double quotes between the single quote and the `+`.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 I think you need another closing bracket in the jQuery expression.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Anthony.  I posted the last comment to this question before I saw your answer.  lol.